# Expo - Firebase fails whenever ExpoGo is in Remote Debug mode

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I'm facing a strange issue that I can't seem to figure out. Recently created a brand new project trying to do everything proper with Firebase v9 SDK. Building in Expo 45. All libraries latest. (Note, I have been building with similar stack for a while -- Expo + RN + Firebase)

Setting up new app scaffolding, everything is great. HOWEVER - when I use Expo Go and turn on remote debugging, it launches the debugger but immediately throws a bunch of Firebase errors:
[image]

If I goto the debug menu and turn off remote debugging, everything is fine. Anyone run into the same and have a solution?

Update:
I've isolated the issue to where I'm registering the onAuthStateChanged() event. In debug mode only, this code throws the errors:

```
export default function Navigation({ colorScheme }: { colorScheme: ColorSchemeName }) {

  const [bUserAuthenticated, setUserAuthenticated] = useState<Boolean>(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      const register = async () => {
        const app = getApp()
        const auth = await getAuth(app)
        // const dispatch = useDispatch()
    
        await auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
          if (user) {
            setUserAuthenticated(true)
            // loadUser()
          } else {
            setUserAuthenticated(false)
          }
        })
      }
      register()

    } catch (err) {
      console.error(`[Navigation.useEffect] ${err}`)
    }
  }, [])
```

Again, without running Expo Go in remote debug mode, this works fine. But when running in remote debug mode, it throws the Firebase unhandled promise exception errors.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there was an issue with the Firebase SDK version I was using (9.8.1). No matter what, whenever it was running in the RN debugger, when getting an instance of any of the modules, it would barf and give an error.

Downgrading to firebase 9.6.1 solved this issue.